# Получить адрес функции для хука

Tags: c++, hook

Я только начинаю вникать в тему "трейнеров" (если я правильно называю) и меня просто вводит в ступор получение адреса функции в чужом процессе для хука. Во всех статьях, что я нашёл приводятся примеры на ассемблере, что для меня на данный момент страшная и непонятная штука. Можете как-то по-простому объяснить эту тему или скинуть какие-то ресурсы для обучения?

Comment: а не могли бы Вы привести пример какой то ссылки, где есть пример такого кода? тогда будет понятнее, о чем именно идет речь

Comment: вот например https://yougame.biz/threads/29468/

Comment: если кратко, нужно получить адрес функции другой программы для вызова или изменения функционала (с помощью инжекта своей dll). (программа с закрытым исходным кодом)

Comment: да, теперь я понял, так устроены разные "читы" к играм. Просто термин "трейнеры" был мне не знаком

Comment: хех, ну я моддингом интересуюсь, если что)

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-нибудь нагуглит этот вопрос, то знайте: без знаний языка ассемблера в этой теме никуда. Вот хорошая статья о хуках: https://www.blast.hk/threads/91079/, можете почитать, но вряд ли разберётесь без понимания работы памяти, процессора и базового асма.